# How to make a case-insensitive index

Tags: indexing

I want to make a book index that is insensitive to case, so that a word at the start of a sentence will be indexed as lower case. My attempts sort of work, they give lowercase items in the index, but there is something hidden in what is being alphabetized, and the listing of "One" and "one" are not the same. Here is what I tried without success:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 

\usepackage{textcase}

\usepackage{makeidx}  \makeindex 

\begin{document}

%This command is designed to display a word that is being indexed
\def\ix#1{#1 \index{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

Indexing this sentence creates three different entries in the index: 

"\ix{One} can have just \ix{one} copy of version \ix{ONE}."

\clearpage
% here is an alternative command

\def\ix#1{#1 \index{\lowercase{#1}}}

"\ix{One} can have just \ix{one} copy of version \ix{ONE}."

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate? [How can I get get makeindex to ignore capital letters?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/129225)

Comment: How should the term be indexed? Like “One”, “one” or “ONE”?

Comment: My choice was that all entries would be "one". But what I get are three separate entries, each of which looks like "one". But they are listed on separate lines, three times.